# Set an id with Handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm trying to put an id with handlebars like this

```html
<script id="tpl" type="text/template">
   {{#each fields.field}}
        <div class="form-group" id="{{name}}">
            <p> Something here </p>
 </div>
   {{/each}}
</script>
```

How I compile my template :

```html
<script>
  var slingshot = function (url, tplId, div) {
  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  var template = $(tplId).html();
  var stone = Handlebars.compile(template)(data);
  $(div).append(stone);
  });
}
slingshot('referentiels.json', '#tpl', '.bs-callout');
</script>
```

But it doesn't work. What is the correct syntax please ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the structure of the `fields` object? Typically an `#each` block would just be something like `{{#each fields}}...{{/each}}`

Comment: My JSON : fields":{
"field":[
{
"name":"something",
"type":"input"
},
{
"name":"something else",
"type":"input"
},
{
"name":"something else",
"type":"select"
},

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your template, and your JSON data seems to check out, so I'm not sure what the cause of the issue could be for you. What is the output after the template is compiled?

Comment: Output is : <div class="form-group" id="{name}">. I want to get <div class="form group" id="something">

Comment: Are you compiling the template client-side or server-side? Can you share the code you are using to compile the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, that was because I've done XSL use. XSL have a syntax which use {}. I so create a conflict between XSL and Handlebars. Then, I just had to put my attributes {{}} into .

Answer (score 0):

Works fine here with your data example:

```js
var source   = document.getElementById("tpl").innerText;
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var data = { fields: { field: [{ name: 'abc' }, { name: 'bcd' }] } };

document.getElementById('result').innerText = template(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.6/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script id="tpl" type="text/template">
 {{#each fields.field}}
  <div class="form-group" id="{{name}}">
       <p> Something here </p>
  </div>
  {{/each}}
</script>

<div id="result">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I wanna load datas from a JSON file :/

Comment: @alexis so just load it from JSON file, what's the problem?

Comment: My {} doesn't compile but it seems that it comes from my serv (apache cocoon) which ignores my {} inside markups

Answer (score 0):

In your compilation code, this line is incorrect:

```
var stone = Handlebars.compile(template)(data);
```

If you are trying to make an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), then it should be:

```
var stone = (Handlebars.compile(template))(data);
```

But really, I think it's much clearer to break it up into two lines:

```
var compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile(template);
var stone = compiledTemplate(data);
```

Comment: If I do this : <div class="form-group" id="{{name}}"><label> {{name}} </label> . The output is <div class="form-group" id="{name}"><label> something </label>

Comment: Have you tried `<div class="form-group" id={{name}}>` instead?

Comment: Yes, I'm working with Apache Cocoon and the error returned is : Open quote is expected for attribute "id" associated with an  element type  "div".

Comment: It's look like it does not compile my {{}} inside the tags. Dunno why coz it works on file:/// but on the serv (I'm using Apache Tomcat) it doesn't compile. In my page, I put a paginator using mustache and onclick on a number of page I get Uncaught Reference.

Comment: Is your HTML markup inside another type of page, like a jsp page? Can you comment out the JavaScript that compiles your template and view the HTML that you get from the server? I bet the outer {} are being stripped from id="{{name}}" before the page is served. You might just need to escape them with \.

Comment: My HTML markup : <html xmlns:fi="http://apache.org/cocoon/forms/1.0#instance"> . I commented out the JS and it seems same. I got a simple pair of {} -> id="{name}"

Comment: That tells me the outer braces are being stripped from id="{{name}}", which is why handlebars isn't parsing it. I don't know Apache Cocoon, but I'd suggest trying to escape the outer braces, like this: id="\{{name}\}", and see if that helps.

Comment: Tried to escape with several ways but nothing goes work ... x).

Comment: It looks like Cocoon's XML processing engine sees curly braces in attributes as an indication of a variable to be replaced, so you might need to escape ALL of the curly braces: `id="\{\{name\}\}"`

Comment: That's not working ... This **** is kidding me so hard x)